# Forbid dll method call in c#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 3D engine. Its API is located in UnityEngine.dll.
Is there a way to block/forbid/make sure some of it's API methods can't be used? It contains some methods that shouldn't be used in my project by other team members even if they accidentally try to. Can this be done in C#?

**UPDATE**: I have no access to code of the library.

Comment: make the methods  private / protected. Or don't you have access to the dll?

Comment: @TimonPost api is contained in compiled engine dll, I have no access to the code

Comment: Oo, that is an other story. But you don't have the source code?

Comment: @TimonPost Sorry, had a typo in previous comment. I have no access to the code

Answer (score 1):

One thing to do could be offering your team members a [facade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) DLL that will only expose the 'allowed' methods.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about this too, but hoped maybe there is some way to at least mark the method not allowed or something similar.

Comment: If you can't modify the original DLL then there is hardly any 'marking' you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You might write some sort of analyzer that checks your scripts for forbidden API calls. Options:

- Analyze the source code by iterating through all Assets of type MonoScript and identify rule violations using Regex tests (easy to implement as long as you are only looking for specific methods, but inaccurate)
- Analyze the compiled code on IL level (accurate but tricky to implement)

You can then have this analyzer invoked automatically:

- After every compilation by using `DidReloadScripts` attribute
- After every build by using `PostProcessBuildAttribute`

I'm not sure if there's a way to make the build fail during post processing, but maybe throwing an Exception when a rule violation is detected will do it.

Comment: Thanks for idea. Maybe I will be able to add this kind of custom analysis to Resharper.